# Как определить ближайшую точку из массива с координатами (X,Y) к главной точке (X,Y)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Необходимо написать функцию `generate_random_coordinates(N)`, которая генерирует кортеж случайных координат (матрицу) длинной N. Координата X в диапазоне от -180 до +180, координата Y от -90 до +90.
2. Написать функцию `find_nearest(coordinate, matrix)`, которая находит ближайшую координату из сгенерированного массива к указанной координате.

Ответ к первому:

```
from random import randint
c = []
def generate_random_coordinates(N):
    for i in range(N):
        c.append([randint(-180, +180),randint(-90, +90)])
    print(c)

z = generate_random_coordinates(7)
print(z)
```

Comment: а что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def generate_random_coordinates(N):
    return [[randint(-180, +180),randint(-90, +90)] for i in range(N)]

main_point = generate_random_coordinates(1)[0]
coords = generate_random_coordinates(10)

def dist(p1, p2=main_point):
    return ((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2) ** 0.5

res = min(coords, key=dist)
```

---

результат:

```
In [105]: coords
Out[105]:
[[-100, 25],
 [-160, -20],
 [-109, -12],
 [158, 79],
 [6, 2],
 [46, -56],
 [75, -81],
 [-109, -71],
 [-75, 40],
 [-177, 57]]

In [106]: main_point
Out[106]: [25, -54]

In [107]: res
Out[107]: [46, -56]
```

Comment: Я тут накалякал так много, а вы в пару строк уложились)

Comment: NB: Корень можно не извлекать, сравнивать квадрат расстояния.

Comment: @MBo, я так и хотел сделать, но потом подумал, что данная функция будет использоваться и для расчёта непосредственно расстояния